# Spring Data Cassandra UDT

Tags: spring, cassandra, user-defined-types

Spring version: 4.3.14
Spring data cassandra version:1.5.10

Hi,
I am using Spring Data Cassandra and I have the following domain object

```
@table
Public class Ticket {
   String tickernum;
   String ticketName;
   List<Subscriber> subscriber;

}


@UserDefinedType()
public class subscriber {
  String imsi;
  String msisdn;
  String name;
}
```

In my cassandra database, I have defined the subscriber to be UDT (user defined type).

I am trying to make a post request with the Ticket payload to "create a ticket"

However, I am getting the following error:

```
12:15:21,259  WARN DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver:384 - Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.datastax.driver.core.UDTValue` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.datastax.driver.core.UDTValue` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried to add empty constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Try `@UserDefinedType` (without parenthesis) for the subscriber UDT